# Error after upgrade from nuxt2.15 to nuxt-bridge

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I was upgrade nuxt2.15 to nuxt-bridge
and run `npm run dev`

but there is error.
I tried to fix it, but I couldn't fix it.

I think this is error about `@nuxt/babel-preset-app`
but, I don't know what should i do.
@nuxt/babel-preset-app version is 2.15.8

this is error log message

```
[nuxt] [request error] Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (68:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
 * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       },
|       maxPrice: {
>         krw: 1_000_000,
|         usd: 900
|       }
  at Object../conf.ts (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:10811:7)  
  at __webpack_require__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:27:30)  
  at Module../node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aimports-transform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt-legacy-vue-transform!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt-legacy-capi-key-transform!./layouts/error.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:30113:63)  
  at __webpack_require__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:27:30)  
  at Module../layouts/error.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:11046:578)  
  at __webpack_require__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:27:30)  
  at Module../layouts/error.vue (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:10998:93)  
  at __webpack_require__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:27:30)  
  at Module../.nuxt/index.js (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:907:76)  
  at __webpack_require__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.js:27:30)
```

Thank you!